# Unenforced references in postgres functions?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

In postgres, When a table/view is updated (e.g. renamed) in a way that will break an existing reference, that reference is also be updated, or the initial update request will fail with an error like:

> ERROR:  cannot drop table users because other objects depend on it

Which is great!

But, those references don't seem to be enforced between functions (or triggers) and tables/views.

So the process:

> (Create TabA) => (Create TabB w/ Ref to TabA) => (Rename TabA to TabC) = No problems

But

> (Create TabA) => (Create FuncA w/ Ref to TabA) => (Rename TabA to TabC) = Quietly broken reference that errors on execution of "FuncA"

Because `FuncA` still points to `TabA`.

Postgres won't allow new functions to be created with nonexistent references, so it's clearly capable of validating references in functions.

So,

- When are references enforced?
- When are references not enforced?
- Is there a way to increase the enforcement level?
- Is there a way to scan an entire database for bad references that may have been introduced?

**EDIT Add Minimal Example**

```
    -- Create users table
    CREATE TABLE users
    (
        id integer NOT NULL,
        name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL
    )

    -- Create function that references "users"
    create function myfunc(int)
        returns text
        language SQL
    AS 
        $BODY$
            select name 
            from users 
            where id = $1 
            limit 1
        $BODY$

    -- Test the function
    select myfunc(1)
    -- (SUCCESS: returns NULL)

    -- Rename users table
    alter table users rename to old_users

    -- Test the function
    select myfunc(1)
    -- (ERROR: relation "users" does not exists SQL state 42P01)
```

Comment: Postgres should be aware of references in the second case.  Perhaps you should provide a (simple) code example.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Phew, thats the answer I was hoping for. Minimal example added. Thanks!

Comment: Although it allows the renaming the referenced table it does not allow to drop the referenced table so it looks like a mixed standard

Comment: [From the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-depend.html): "*For user-defined functions, PostgreSQL tracks dependencies associated with a function's externally-visible properties, such as its argument and result types, but not dependencies that could only be known by examining the function body*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that currently there isn't really a way when initially loading a function for PostgreSQL to always know what its dependencies are.  While such would probably not be that hard to add to SQL-language functions, even with dynamic SQL in PL/PGSQL functions this becomes effectively impossible.  Go further afield to C, PL/Perl, PL/Python, etc. functions and you have no hope of any guarantee.

So functions are a special case.  It is worth noting they are almost always planner opaque and in fact they are generally opaque to PostgreSQL as a whole.  And so for this reason you need to think carefully about when and where to use them, how to test, etc.

Fortunately there are things like `pg_TAP` and other testing frameworks which let you check that functions still work.